# How to check if two users have private chat? SQL

Tags: sql, database, linq, subquery, where-clause

[image]

How to write sql or linq query to check if two users have common private chat (isGroup==false)

Answer (score 1):

If I follow you  correctly, you can filter the `chats` table with two `exists` subqueries, once for each user you want the common chats for:

```
select c.*
from chats c
where 
    isGroup = 0
    and exists (select 1 from participants p where p.chatID = c.id and p.participantId = ?)
    and exists (select 1 from participants p where p.chatID = c.id and p.participantId = ?)
```

This gives you one row for each private chat that both users have in common.

Comment: Alothough both answers are correct and fine, this approach is recommended because the result needs only columns from `chat` and that's where `exists` comes as handy

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 depending on the existing / non-existing indexes on the tables, an `EXISTS` subquery may be quite slow, and it has to be done twice for each row in the Chats table.

Comment: @derpirscher reagarding index, it applies to join too. In this particular case `chat` table has least records so assuming indexes are in place `exists` will be preferable over `join`

Comment: As I said earlier I am completely in agreement with both query and just wanted to add some more information to it.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 Therefore I wrote "*may* be quite slow". To find out which of the proposed solutions fits best, one has to do performance checks ...

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. Depending on your row count and existing indexes the approaches may perform quite differently

1. You can do two `INNER JOIN`s between the `Chats` and the `Participants` table and check for the desired `participantid` in each of them (each of the `?` stands for one of the ids in a parameterized query) This will return all nongroup chats where (at least) the two desired users are involved

   ```
   SELECT c.*
    FROM chats c 
      INNER JOIN participants p1 ON p1.chatid = c.id AND p1.participantid = ?
      INNER JOIN participants p2 ON p2.chatid = c.id AND p2.participantid = ?
    WHERE 
      c.isgroup = 0
   ```
2. Another possibility (maybe less efficient) could be querying the `Participants` for all chats where at least the desired users are involved and then joining this result with the `Chats` table and filter for private chats.

   ```
    WITH userchats(chatid) AS (
      SELECT chatid
      FROM participants
      WHERE participantid IN (?, ?)
      GROUP BY chatid
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
    SELECT c.*
      FROM chats c
        INNER JOIN userchats uc ON c.chatid = uc.chatid
    WHERE 
      c.isgroup = 0
   ```
3. You can do as @GMB [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63548915/3776927) and use an `EXISTS` subquery.